# docker and 2 asp net core apps

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have another question about dockerizing apps :)

I've started 2 net core apps - backend (rest api) and asp.netcore as tiny client (frontend)

so my docker-compose looks like

```
version: "3"

services:
    randevou-rest-backend:
        build: "./randevou_netCore"
        ports:
            - "7777:7777"

    randevou-mvc-client:
        build: "./RandevouMVC/RandevouClientMVC"
        ports:
            - "8003:8888"
```

in my randevou-mvc-client i have endpoint as static string in some configFile, sth like:

```
const _backendEndpoint = "0.0.0.0:7777";
```

the problem is, when i run it by docker-compose up, both containers have different ip's:

```
pawel@pawel-E6412T-MD99372:~/repo$ docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' a59b9030702a
172.18.0.2
pawel@pawel-E6412T-MD99372:~/repo$ docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' fcec060db89a
172.18.0.3
```

i have read that i can set service name as endpoint-address, but i would like to have this same code (ip address) for dockerizing and running app straight from my system (like dotnet run myMVCClient.dll)

when i use docker run myMvcClientImage instead of docker-compose, everything is fine.

Comment: These are 2 separate containers, so they have 2 different IPs. You should use Docker DNS like `randevou-rest-backend:7777` instead of `0.0.0.0:7777`

Comment: i could use but it will be different code if i want to use app in container or straight in the system typing 'dotnet run ...' also i don't know, why 2 other clients (running by npm on docker) works fine with connecting to endpoint ip '0.0.0.0:7777'

Comment: You do not have to hardcode any configurations in code. Use the environment variables. Try `localhost:7777` then

Comment: Roman, i can't use localhost :)
i think that 2 net core app running on kestrel can't work on same ip address,

Comment: Why not? " i think that 2 net core app running on kestrel can't work on same ip address" -  Why do you think so? It is not true. 2 app can't work on the same port but not IP

Comment: ok, so how can i set my docker-compose file for these 2 containers works on same ip ? 
or even these two services works in one container?

Comment: You cannot set 2 containers works on the same IP! And it is a bad practice to run two services works in one container, but possible, try google. You need or 2 separate containers or 1 container with one service (merge backend  and frontend in one project)

Comment: so what i have to do to solve the problem :) ?

Comment: run 2 containers on different ports and configure frontend service by the environment variables to use randevou-rest-backend:7777 or localhost:7777